# Doctrine Multiple One-To-Many Relations on same table

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, one-to-many

I have a little Problem with Doctrine and Yaml:

Here is my Model:

```
 Keyword:
  columns:
    word: { type: string, notnull: true }
    is_stopword: { type: boolean, default: 0 }
    has_parents: { type: boolean, default: 0 }

Relation:
  columns:
    child: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    parent: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Keyword: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: [child, parent], foreign: id }
```

Somehow, i can't get Doctrine to bind both relations, only the first one (child) gets connected to "Keyword"... Since a Child can have many Parents, and a Parent many Childs, this is the only way i see to solve this... Any tipps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define two relations, one for parent and one for child.
This `local: [child, parent]` won't work, for each relation you have to define one local and one foreign field.

```
Relation:
  columns:
    child: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    parent: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    ChildKeyword: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: child, foreign: id }
    ParentKeyword: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: parent, foreign: id }
```